# Debian - Port 80 is blocked, but I don't know by what

Tags: debian, port, analysis

I can't make lighttpd listen to port 80.

```
~# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
Starting web server: lighttpd2013-03-16 23:15:02: (network.c.379) can't bind to port:  80 Address already in use
 failed!
```

Actually I have apache2 installed on my server, too (listening to port 80) but it is not active.

I used netstat /  netstat -npl but it wasn't helpful

How can I figure out what is using the port?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In depsite of people got used to [`netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) for such kind of operations, it's good to know, that Linux has another great (and, actually superior) networking tool — [`ss`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss). For e. g., *to find out which process has opened port 80* you run it so:

`sudo ss -pt state listening 'sport = :80'`

so there's no need to pipe through external filters. Surely it has lots more useful knobs, so get yourself familiar with it.

For completeness sake and since recently I came across [`man fuser`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser), I can also mention:

- `sudo fuser 80/tcp` — this one also saves you from tinkering at `cut`/`grep`/`awk`… keep in mind this notation is a short-cut, in case there's an ambiguity, you should use one of namespaces allowed with `-n …`, like `sudo fuser -n tcp 80`
- `sudo lsof -n -sTCP:LISTEN -i:80` — was [pointed out](https://serverfault.com/a/488535/67675) by @[wallenborn](https://serverfault.com/users/19878/wallenborn). Meanwhile `-n` is not strictly required it's strongly advised since otherwise it uses DNS resolving which usualy slows down output terribly.

Comment: @Goot, if you mean binary, yep, at least `ls -l /proc/PID/exe` would do. And you mean its current work dir, see `…/cwd`.

Answer (score 6):

`Address already in use` means that another process is already listening on port 80. Only one process can listen on a given port at a time.

To find the process, run as root:

```
netstat -tnlp | grep -w 80
```

The offending process will be listed.

Comment: thanks, I figured out there is another instance of lighttpd running. I will accept your answer when it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Another option with fewer keystrokes is lsof:

```
lsof -i :80
```

Comment: Nope. It show not only listening processes.

Comment: Correct use is a bit more longer: `lsof -n -sTCP:LISTEN -i:22`

Comment: Correct use is a bit more longer: `sudo lsof -n -sTCP:LISTEN -i:80`. And it's better to use `sudo` explicitly to emphasize that unless user has superior permissions he might not be able to get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but who knows, someone has the same problem I had. In Apache2 I had more than one site enabled. In one of the site configurations (/etc/apache2/sites-available) the first line was

```
listen 80
```

This caused a conflict with Apache itself! Because it was already listening on port 80 as a global config.
Just remove the 'listen 80' from yoursite.conf if Apache has port 80 as a default port.